# How can I create a XAML template that acts as a wrapper for elements?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML code:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="1" HasShadow="false" Margin="10" 
 BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Silver" Padding="0" >
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Padding="0" >
      <xaml:PtiXaml />
      <template:LineTemplate />
      <xaml:AtiXaml />
      <template:LineTemplate />
      <xaml:StiXaml />
   </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could replace this with something like:

```
<template:NewFrame>
      <xaml:PtiXaml />
      <template:LineTemplate />
      <xaml:AtiXaml />
      <template:LineTemplate />
      <xaml:StiXaml />
</template:NewFrame>
```

As you can see I'm familiar with how to create and use templates that contain elements, but I don't know how to create a template that I can use as a wrapper for elements.

Comment: Create custom view that inherits from Frame.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this.

Comment: follow this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Comment: One more option you can try. Create different templates in your XAML and depending on the type set that template to your view.

Answer (score 2):

One way is the one that @Tom said and another one is using a [Control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/) that is basically what you want I think.

Even tough the docs said that

> Xamarin.Forms control templates provide the ability to easily theme and re-theme application pages at runtime. This article provides an introduction to control templates

you can use the control template as a wrapper using it in a `ContentView` (I've done it and it works perfectly).

In your case you'd have to do a `ContentView` and fill the `ContentView.ControlTemplate` with your layout of the wrapper:

```xml
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:... your namespaces
    x:Class="YourNamespace.NewFrame">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Frame CornerRadius="1" HasShadow="false" Margin="10" 
                BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Silver" Padding="0" >
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

As you can see there is a `ContentPresenter` that is what is going to be replaced with your content (one thing to take into account is that the `ContentPresenter` allows only one child so you wil have to put your `StackLayout` inside)

```xml
<template:NewFrame>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Padding="0" >
        <xaml:PtiXaml />
        <template:LineTemplate />
        <xaml:AtiXaml />
        <template:LineTemplate />
        <xaml:StiXaml />
    </StackLayout>
</template:NewFrame>
```

---

Another way would be to do a [custom layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom) but it's more complicated and I wouldn't go that way to do that layout wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

### C#:

```cs
public class CustomFrame : Frame
{
    public CustomEditor()
    {
        CornerRadius = 1;
        HasShadow = false;
        Margin = 10;
        BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        BorderColor = Color.Silver;
        Padding = 0;
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```xml
<template:CustomFrame>
    <StackLayout 
        Orientation="Vertical" 
        Spacing="0" 
        Padding="0" >

        <xaml:PtiXaml />
        <template:LineTemplate />
        <xaml:AtiXaml />
        <template:LineTemplate />
        <xaml:StiXaml />

    </StackLayout>
</template:CustomFrame>
```